# How to add separators (vertical lines) in the dock?

Tags: macos, dock

Is this even possible? Could be very handy for me.

**Here is an example:**
I have some folders right next to the trash bin. Sometimes I accidentally put a file in the trash bin instead of in the folder.

Comment: Mojave added two vertical separators, one for recent apps, and one for "Downloads and Trash"

Comment: @ankii, **macOS Mojave** only added one separator to the **Dock** for the **Dock** preference **[] Show recent application in the Dock**, not two as you so state. The one for minimized windows, Downloads and Trash existed before **macOS Mojave**.

Comment: @user3439894 Having not spent much time on High Sierra, my memory must have been mistaken to forget the already existing one, thus attributing both to Mojave.

Comment: @ankii, There has always been one separator as far back as **Mac OS X 10.0 Cheetah**, in the 10.x line, until **macOS Mojave**.

Comment: @user3439894 I am not very old.. also bought my laptop with High Sierra. Thanks for the info though!

Answer (score 1):

You can put a spacer in the dock that separated documents from the trash. This is not the same as the vertical line, but may help you. From the terminal type or paste:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock persistent-others -array-add '{tile-data={}; tile-type="spacer-tile";}'
```

after that run

```
killall Dock
```

The Dock will disappear briefly but reappear with new setting. This spacer is like an icon and can be moved along the Dock by clicking and moving the spacer to where you want it. The source I included has methods for customized spacers. It may show you how to add a vertical line.

Removing them is similar to removing any other icon from the dock. Click, hold and drag it out.

Source https://www.lifewire.com/add-custom-and-standard-doc-spacers-to-mac-2260861